# ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1 in assembled Spark jar file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, sbt-assembly

I am running Spark application from jar file. When I define in log4j custom file and run my application simply from the main class the logs output works fine, however, when I run the application from jar file I get such an error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not create the Layout. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseLayout(DOMConfigurator.java:555)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:269)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.initializeLogIfNecessary(SparkSubmit.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [Json].
```

What could be the reason of JSONEventLayoutV1 not to be found in dependencies, although it is defined in build.sbt.

Log4j file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="Json" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.hadoop.log.Log4Json">
            <param name="PatternLayout" value=""/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Json"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

My build.sbt file:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"
val circeVersion = "0.11.0"

dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.5"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % "it, test",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "it, test",
  "io.kubernetes" % "client-java" % "3.0.0" % "it",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20180813",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.7",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.7",
  "net.logstash.log4j" % "jsonevent-layout" % "1.7"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if x.endsWith(".conf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "logging", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "beanutils", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "collections", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "hadoop", "yarn", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "objenesis", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("com", "sun", "jersey", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "hadoop", "yarn", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "slf4j", "impl", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("com", "codahale", "metrics", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "transaction", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "inject", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "xml", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("META-INF", "jersey-module-version") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("plugin.xml") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("parquet.thrift") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("codegen", "config.fmpp") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("git.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("overview.html") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Spark loads the log4j config before it loads the application jar.
To fix this, I added the following jars to the driver and executor class paths:

"spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/etl/jsonevent-layout-1.7.jar:/etl/json-smart-1.1.1.jar",
"spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/etl/jsonevent-layout-1.7.jar:/etl/json-smart-1.1.1.jar"

Note: json-smart is a dependency of jsonevent-layout.

Note: Make sure that jars are present on the spark nodes.